# What are more efficient ways to loop through a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python

I need to extract some data from 37,000 xls files, which are stored in 2100 folders (activity/year/month/day). I already wrote the script, however when given a small sample of a thousand files, it takes 5 minutes to run. Each individual file can include up to ten thousand entries I need to extract. Haven't tried running it on the entire folder, I'm looking for suggestions how to make it more efficient.

I would also like some help on how to export the dictionary to a new excel file, two columns, or how to skip the entire dictionary and just save directly to xls, and how to point the entire script at a shared drive folder, instead of Python's root.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import pandas as pd

docid = []
CoCo = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Z_Option'):
    for filename in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, 'Z_*.xls'):
            df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root, filename), sheet_name='Sheet0')

            for i in df['BLDAT']:
                if isinstance(i, int):
                    docid.append(i)
                    CoCo.append(df['BUKRS'].iloc[1])

data = dict(zip(docid, CoCo))
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This walkthrough](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6?gi=351937629aa3) was very helpful for me when I was beginning with pandas. What is likely taking so long is the `for i in df['BLDAT']` line.

Using something like an apply function can offer a speed boost:

```
def check_if_int(row): #row is effectively a pd.Series of the index
    if type(row['BLDAT']) == 'int':
        docid.append(i)
        CoCo.append(row.name) #name should be the index

df.apply(check_if_int, axis = 1) #axis = 1 will work rowwise
```

It's unclear what exactly this script is trying to do, but if it's as simple as filtering the dataframe to only include rows where the `'BLDAT'` column is an integer, using a mask would be much faster

```
df_filtered = df.loc[type(df['BLDAT']) == 'int'] #could also use .isinstance()
```

Another advantage of filtering the dataframe as opposed to creating lists is the ability to use the pandas function `df_filtered.to_csv()` to output the file as an .xlsx compatible file.

Comment: I need to pull all accounting document ids along with the company code, posted by an Excel macro in SAP for the past three years. The BLDAT column has the docids, but every second row is empty (NaN in pandas), and there's some text at the top too.  The BUKRS column is just the company code.

I need the if statement to filter for numerical values (the document ids)

I will then need to dump all docids, along with the company code in a new file.

Comment: why can't you just do something like `df.dropna(subset = ['BLDAT'], inplace = True)` to get rid of the empty rows?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vUNOgkP - this is how the dataframe looks like.

tried the 

`df_filtered = df.loc[type(df['BLDAT']) == 'int']  #could also use .isinstance()` I got a bunch of errors, will try to troubleshoot tomorrow, it's already 10 pm here

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I gave up due to time constraints (yay last minute "I need this tomorrow" reports), and came up with this. Dropping empty rows helped by some margin, and for the next quarter I'll try to do this entirely with pandas.

```
#Shared drive
import fnmatch
import os
import pandas as pd
import time

start_time = time.time()
docid = []
CoCo = []
os.chdir("X:\Shared activities")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("folder"):
    for filename in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, 'Z_*.xls'):
            try:
                df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root, filename), sheet_name='Sheet0')
                df.dropna(subset = ['BLDAT'], inplace = True)
                for i in df['BLDAT']:
                    if isinstance(i, int):
                        docid.append(i)
                        CoCo.append(df['BUKRS'].iloc[1])
            except:
                errors.append((os.path.join(root, filename)))

data = dict(zip(docid, CoCo))
os.chdir("C:\project\reports")
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index").to_csv('test.csv')
with open('errors.csv', 'w') as f:
    for item in errors:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```